# To show that the complement of the embedded interval in R^2 is path connected

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $c:I\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be continuous injective curve.
How can I show that $\mathbb{R}^2-{\rm im}(c)$ is path connected?

I first guessed and tried to show that pair $(\mathbb{R}^2,{\rm im}(c))$ is homeomorphic(or homotopic)
to ($\mathbb{R}^2$, linear segment) But I'm not sure that this is correct and even if this
is true, it seems to tough for me.

Next I tried to use homology theory, some mayer vietoris sequence but I'm not
making any progress now. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The question is: what do you know? Do you know that if $A\neq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $B\neq \mathbb{R}^n$ are closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic, then $H^p(\mathbb{R}^n - A) \cong H^p(\mathbb{R}^n -B)?$

Comment: Mayer-Vietoris would work. If you know Alexander Duality, that gives a quick proof.

Comment: In case $c\colon [0,2\pi[\to \mathbb R$, $c(t):=\bigl(\cos(t),\sin(t)\bigr)$, then $\mathbb R\setminus c([0,2\pi[)$ is path connected?!  What am I missing?

Comment: @bigdeal And what about $I:=\mathbb R$, $c(t):=(t,t)$?  I presume $I$ has to be compact for the assertion to be true.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: $I$ is standard notation for the unit interval.

Comment: $I$ see, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that for any embedding of a closed interval $c\subset \mathbb R^2$, the pair $(\mathbb R^2,c )$ is homeomorphic to $(\mathbb R^2, I)$ where $I$ is standardly embedded. See [this math.overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57766/why-are-there-no-wild-arcs-in-the-plane) that addresses this. As you suspect, it is a difficult statement to prove.

My idea to apply Mayer Vietoris was to let $U$ be the complement of the curve and let $V$ be an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $c$, but I don't see how to easily argue that $U\cap V$ is connected, which is what you'd need for this argument to work.

The easiest way I see to do the problem requires the machinery of Alexander Duality: if $X$ is a compact, locally contractible subspace of $S^n$, then $\widetilde{H}_q(S^n\setminus X)\cong \widetilde{H}^{n-q-1}(X),$ where $\widetilde{H}$ stands for reduced homology and cohomology. So in our case $\widetilde{H}_0(S^2\setminus c)\cong H^1(c)=0$. So $S^2\setminus c$ is path connected. Removing a point from $S^2$ yields $\mathbb R^2$. Since it is easy to arrange for a path to miss a point, $\mathbb R^2\setminus c$ is connected as well.